# iOS drawRect and cornerRadius. How does it work?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, calayer, drawrect

I don't understand why a simple view, with only `cornerRadius` property set to an arbitrary value, works perfectly, while as soon as i override drawRect ( also trying to call `super.drawRect()` ) `cornerRadius` doesn't work anymore. The solution is to set `self.layer.masksToBounds` property to true, but i don't understand the structure of what happens behind the code, such as what functions are called first. The documentation about `cornerRadius` doesn't help me.

Any suggestions/explanation ?

Thx

Comment: Why do you want to override `drawRect`? What do you want to achieve with it? It's often not necessary to do so.

Comment: when you override drawrect, you indicate that you are going to render the view. Either set all the property to the view and allow the framework to render or override the drawrect and render the way you want.

Comment: ok Naveen, but how can you explain the fact that setting masksToBounds true makes cornerRadius works although i decided to override drawRect?

Michal i'm just practising with a custom view.